# Erro ao adicionar itens a um arquivo .txt Python3

Tags: python-3.x, txt

Estou tentando ler um arquivo .txt (Atualmente vazio) para verificar se o chat_id já existe, se já existir, ele termina ali mesmo. Caso não exista... Adiciona o novo chat_id na última linha, mas quando rodo o código e vejo o arquivo, não há nada escrito nele e não apresenta nenhum erro no terminal... Onde estou errando?

```
def add_chat(self):
    #print(self.msg_chat_id) output: -10052348214
    with open('bot_chat_ids.txt', 'r') as allchats:
        for chat in allchats:
            if str(self.msg_chat_id) == chat:
                return
    with open('bot_chat_ids.txt', 'a') as allchats:
        allchats.write(str(self.msg_chat_id) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Seu código está quase correto, porém está demasiado.

O método `open` permite a associação de mais de uma regra para abertura do arquivo, no caso `r+`, significa leitura e escrita, então você não precisa acessar o arquivo duas vezes.

O demais do seu código estava praticamente igual, apenas foi agrupado as funções com a abertura de arquivo correta.

```
#print(self.msg_chat_id) output: -10052348214
with open('bot_chat_ids.txt', 'r+') as allchats:
    for chat in allchats.readlines():
        chat = re.sub(' +','',chat)
        chat = chat.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '')
        if str(self.msg_chat_id) == chat:
            return

    allchats.write(str(self.msg_chat_id) + '\r')
```

Obs: no meu exemplo tive de limpar as strings para funcionar corretamente.

Para o funcionamento do métodu `sub`, é necessário importar o module `re` no arquivo:

```
import re
```

Os parâmetros ' +','' e chat, indica para remover todos os espaços a direita e substituir por nada na string `chat`.

```
Já com o método `replace` retiramos todas as quebras de linhas.
```

O arquivo txt estava da seguinte forma:

```
-1651654165132
-6513216545
-561652132132
-65163214551
```

Comment: Pode explicar melhor a parte do re.sub()? É um modulo o re?

Comment: ah sim, vou comentar na resposta